# How to read JSON from external URL and display in a block?

Tags: 7

I want to load some JSON data from an external URL and display it in a block.

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most basic solution, you would need to:

- Create a custom module;
- Implement [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to define your block (see [block_example.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example--block_example.module/7) for examples);
- When generating the block content, use [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) to retrieve the json data from your URL and process the return value as needed.

A more complex version of your custom module could for instance involve implementing [hook_block_configure](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7) to make the URL configurable from the UI, using theme functions to generate the HTML output, and caching/storage of the return value.

A completely different approach, which may or may not be appropiate in your case, would be to use the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to retrieve the JSON and store the data as nodes, and use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to generate a block listing those nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too simple of an approach, but if all you truly want to do is display JSON data (no need to store it), then I'd add a new block as "Full HTML" and then add some JQuery.

To embed an HTML snippet it would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remoteFeed').load('http://example.com/path/to/page #some-div-id');
});
})(jQuery);
</script><div id="remoteFeed"></div>
```

The method would be similar for JSON, only you'd have to do some formatting of the return that would be custom to your application.

Here's a working example pulled from [JQuery.getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) customized ever so slightly to work inside a Drupal Block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "awesome",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#flickr-images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
<div id="flickr-images"></div>
```

Comment: pretty cool, thanks. The json doesn't change often so I might be better off storing or caching it, that should improve the load time

Comment: Not necessarily. Depends on whose server is faster: your server or the JSON resource? True, there will always be a delay when for JQuery to load after the document renders. If you decide to cache the result, a lightweight approach drupal way would be to use drupal_http_request as @marcvangend advised and store the result in a revisioned node for history.